# Convert a var of class "str" to class "socket.socket"

Tags: python, csv, sockets

I saved a socket variable to a CSV file, and it turns into a string (for example, `<socket.socket fd=1608, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 5693), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 56052)>`) so I can't use it now.

Is there any way to convert it back into a socket after reading this string from the CSV file?

Or, is there a way to save the socket to the CSV file without it turning into a string to begin with?

I tried using `literal_eval` from ast, but to no avail.

Comment: You cannot store a socket in a csv file.

Comment: it is stored as in the example I gave in the post
"<socket.socket fd=1608, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 5693), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 56052)>"

Comment: This is not a socket, its a textual representation of what python knows about the socket. you _can not_ store a socket in a csv file.

Comment: But is there a way to convert this string represtation of a socket to a socket which i would send the data with?

Comment: Store the remote address and (re)connect whenever you want, there is no other way.

Comment: You could write some code that would parse the socket object's string representation then reconstruct it but it would be much easier if you simply save the values that you used to construct it in the first place

Comment: A socket is an ephemeral network connection. Once the socket is closed the connection is gone. What possible benefit could there be to saving it in a file? If you want to enable another process/thread to use the socket then there are programming tools to address that particular case.